# How do I take a url and rename it to a .mp4 using wget?

Tags: wget

Need help for a project and have a bunch of URLs that need to be renamed to .mp4     Here are some of them 1280x720.mp4 - 640x360.mp4 - 320x180.3gp

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. A URL is not a video, and renaming it to a .mp4 doesn't make it a video either. They're completely different things.

Comment: those filenames aren't URLs either; sizes perhaps, but not URLs.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you have a bunch of URLs leading to videos, and you want to download them with wget, you could run this for each video:

```
wget -c yoururlhere -O yourlocalfilepathhere.mp4
```

`-c` means that downloads can resume if they are interrupted (useful, but not essential)

`yoururlhere` could be 'http://example.com/1280x720.mp4'.

`yourlocalfilepathhere.mp4` could be 'C:/Users/YourName/Desktop/1280x720.mp4'.

Alternatively, you could put all your URLs in a text file and use this:

```
wget -c -i yourtextfilelocation.txt -O yourlocalfilepathhere.mp4
```

`yourtextfilelocation.txt` could be 'C:/Users/YourName/Desktop/my_url_list.txt'

Hope this is what you were looking for :)